# Pass Variable From Code To Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am passing a value to a stored procedure, but it keeps giving me an error of error converting data type nvarchar to int.  What needs to be altered to remove the error?  Below is my actual call, and the stored procedure

```
private static string ReturnPhoneNumber()
{
string username = "Roy Orbinson";
string databaseConnection = "Data Source=EmployeeServer;Initial Catalog=StoreInfo;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"; 
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(databaseConnection);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GimmeThatPhoneNumber", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.Parameters.Add("@username", username);

connection.Open();
var result = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
connection.Close();

return result;
}
```

SQL:

```
[dbo].[GimmeThatPhoneNumber]
(
@username int
)

as

Set NoCount On

SELECT phonenumber
FROM personelinformation
where employeename = @username
```

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that your input parameter has an `int` type - but needs to be a string type:

```
[dbo].[GimmeThatPhoneNumber]
(
    @username int
)
```

`@username` should be:

```
@username nvarchar(200) --pick an appropriate size
```

Comment: It's also possible that the parameter is user ID (vs name) and the code needs to first look up the userid associated with that user name

Answer (score 0):

you are passing @username with the value of username. but you the variable username is a string and in your stored procedure you defined @username as integer.
you should either change the type of @username in the procedure to nvarchar or convert the string username to int.